# Is it possible to duplicate an EE3 build over to a brand new license/server/database?

Tags: ee3, duplicate

Both builds are exactly the same just with different branding. Just looking for the easiest way to set this up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be no more complicated than:

- copy the file stack from the first server to the second
- use a utility (e.g. phpmyadmin) to export the EE database from your first server to a file
- import the database to your new server using a utility (e.g. phpmyadmin)
- update the `config.php` file on the new server to point to the right paths and to the new database, and insert the EE serial number for the second server
- log into the EE control panel on the new server (credentials will be same as on first server) and fine-tune the settings to get it working OK on new server
- do your branding changes to the new server

You can save yourself some time if you like by updating the EE settings on the first copy to use `{base_url}` and `{base_path}` in the various file locations used to configure EE in the CP - then when you change these two entries on the new server, all the entries in CP that use them will be automagically updated too...

HTH